How to throw error in vim that silently fails without printing any message?
I have a vim function that moves the cursor. It may also throw an error. A simplified version for illustrative purpose is:
" Move cursor to the 1st line. Errors if the cursor was on the 2nd line.
function! FirstLineErrorOut()
    let l:curr_line = line(".")
    call cursor(1, 1)
    if l:curr_line == 2
        throw "error"
    endif
endfunction

I then bind a key to it in operator-pending mode:
onoremap lb :call FirstLineErrorOut()<cr>

What I want to achieve is to complete the actions before the error (i.e. positioning the cursor), and then abort the operator-pending mode by throwing an error (see https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#map-error), yet without showing any error message (i.e. "Error detected while processing function ... E605: Exception not caught: error").
The mapping currently positions the cursor, aborts the operator-pending mode, but does show error messages and needs the user to press <enter> to continue, which I'd like to avoid.
Note that this effect is achievable with builtin vim keys like b and ge (see discussion at https://stackoverflow.com/a/79261518/7881370), where the cursor is positioned to the first line while deletion (d) is not executed.
Things I've tried with no luck:

onoremap <silent> lb :call FirstLineErrorOut()<cr>: the error message still shows up.
onoremap <silent> lb :silent call FirstLineErrorOut()<cr>: the error message still shows up.
onoremap lb :silent! call FirstLineErrorOut()<cr>: the error message is suppressed, but the operator-pending mode is not aborted either.
Add redir @a and redir END before and after throw "error" in FirstLineErrorOut() definition: the error message still shows up, although it's also sent to register @a.
Surround throw "error" with try ... catch ... endtry: the operator-pending mode won't get aborted of course.

Thank you so much!

There are two approaches to this problem (which is much broader than programming, BTW): 1. try to do the thing and handle eventual failure, 2. only do the thing if the conditions are right. You followed the former (risky, can break in lots of ways, requires workarounds, etc.), while I would follow the latter (safer, simpler). In other words, do if l:curr_line != 2 before call cursor(1, 1).

I need to find a way to trigger map-error in order to abort subsequent omap, and throwing an error is the only approach I know to be effective. If we do nothing in the function to be omapped, as you said, it will be equivalent to calling cursor(line("."), col(".")) in that function, and subsequent operator will take effect. In particular, for inclusive motion, o_v is needed in omap, resulting in dv:call MoveCursorFunction() to delete the character at the cursor position. Happy to know other methods!

My suggestion is not to do nothing but to do the thing only if it is possible instead of doing it no matter what and then dealing with the eventual fallout. You can avoid doing the thing while still throwing an error.

@romainl I accidentally found a solution, kind of inspired by your advice. Thank you so much!

The trick is to first cancel the operator-pending mode, and then reactivate it depending on certain condition. Inspired by the example at vimhelp. Code:
" Move cursor to the 1st line, run the operator
" unless the cursor was on the 2nd line.
function! FirstLineErrorOut(operator)
    let l:curr_line = line(".")
    if l:curr_line == 2
        call cursor(1, 1)
    else
        execute "normal! " . a:operator . ":call cursor(1, 1)\<cr>"
    endif
endfunction

onoremap lb <esc>:call FirstLineErrorOut(v:operator)<cr>

